# Chinese names for Lunar Features?

Tags: place-names

Are there names in Chinese for craters and other features on the Moon? Or are English/International names used instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the name of the craters on the moon, I would say international names are used, just like the naming of the stars.

By the way, some craters are named after Chinese people, like [万户撞击坑](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wan-Hoo_(crater)) and so on.

If you are talking about the features in general, we do have names for them

> 陨石坑 - crater
>
> 月海 - lunar mare
>
> [月相](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E7%9B%B8) - lunar phase